# RACSignal combineLatest using multiple UIControls

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I'm experimenting with [Reactive Cocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) and I'm having trouble combining signals from multiple UIControls.

I am creating an editor for UIEdgeInsets and have four UISteppers, for the top, left, bottom and right insets.

What I *want* to do is this:

```
RAC(self.insets) = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[
          [topStepper rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged],
          [leftStepper rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged],
          [bottomStepper rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged],
          [rightStepper rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]
          ] reduce:^(UIStepper *top, UIStepper *left, UIStepper *bottom, UIStepper *right) {
              return [NSValue valueWithUIEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top.value, left.value, bottom.value, right.value)];
          }];
```

However, this never results in the  signal being processed.

If I only include one signal, like this:

```
RAC(self.insets) = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[
    [topStepper rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]]
    reduce:^(UIStepper *top) {
        return [NSValue valueWithUIEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top.value, 0.0,0.0,0.0)];
    }];
```

It works as expected (observing any of the other steppers individually works fine as well) but for multiple controls, I get nothing. I can work around by observing each control as a separate signal, but that seems to miss the point of the `combineLatest` method. Am I doing something wrong, or should I be raising an issue on the RAC project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because in order for `combineLatest:reduce:` to run, each of the controls in that array must have broadcast at least one signal to start with (any non-mutated values for signals observing latest will not call the reduce block).  You can see it quite clearly, because each of those controls must be tapped at least once to begin producing valid signals, which get thrown in and processed like you'd expect.  As noted by Justin, you can make the signal have an initial value, which should get the proper values up and running far quicker than calling `-sendActionForControlEvent:`

```
RAC(self.insets) = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[
                    [[self.topStepper rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]startWith:nil],
                    [[self.leftStepper rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]startWith:nil],
                    [[self.bottomStepper rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]startWith:nil],
                    [[self.rightStepper rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]startWith:nil]
                    ] reduce:^(UIStepper *top, UIStepper *left, UIStepper *bottom, UIStepper *right) {
                        return [NSValue valueWithUIEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top.value, left.value, bottom.value, right.value)];
                    }];
```

Comment: Makes sense, but it's dirty.

Comment: You can use `-startWith:` to give a signal an initial value. Also, nil values do _not_ cancel a `+combineLatest:`. They'll get passed into the reduce block like any other value.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers when I ran a test with his code, neither the reduce block, nor the setter were being called until all four of the stepper's values had been mutated.  Perhaps cancel wasn't the right choice of words.

Comment: Correct, `+combineLatest:` is not invoked until all signals have sent at least one value. But `nil` is a completely valid value for a signal to send, and all four steppers sending `nil` would trigger the block successfully.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers Better?

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers so are you saying my existing code should be working? Is this answer wrong? The original answer (sending the control events) did work, but it seemed unnecessary.

Comment: The corrected answer here will work properly, although convention is usually to apply `-startWith:` to each individual signal. The original code in the question would not work for the reasons mentioned above. See also the documentation for `+combineLatest:` and `-startWith:`, which explains their respective behaviors.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers The "corrected" answer does _not_ work. And I can't find the documentation to which you refer - do you mean the comments included in the code headers, or have I missed something else? Calling startWith on each signal does work.

Comment: @jrturton Ah, sorry, quite right. The reason it doesn't work is the same reason that the original sample didn't work – the first value simply skips over the problem, but it reappears when you want the second. Re: documentation: yep, all of it is in the headers.

Comment: @CodaFi startWith:@0 doesn't work (it crashes because the reduce block is expecting a stepper). startWith:nil does work, and seems the cleanest. I've edited that in and re-accepted you, thanks for the help!